# How to fix getPlayerState for Youtube API to return int value?

Tags: javascript, python, selenium, youtube-api, youtube-javascript-api

ERROR:

> selenium.common.exceptions.JavascriptException: Message: javascript error: Cannot read property 'getPlayerState' of null

or

> Message: javascript error: getPlayerState is not a function

HTML Code:

```
<div id="movie_player"></div>
```

Javascript Code:

```
<script src="http://www.youtube.com/player_api"></script>

<script>
// create youtube player
var player;
var video_id = 'qCTMq7xvdXU';
let player_vars = {"playsinline": 1, "origin": "https://www.youtube.com"}
  function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
    player = new YT.Player('movie_player', {
      height: '390',
      width: '640',
      videoId: 'M7lc1UVf-VE',
      events: {
        'onReady': onPlayerReady,
        'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
      }
    });
  }

  // 4. The API will call this function when the video player is ready.
  function onPlayerReady(event) {
    event.target.playVideo();
  }

  // 5. The API calls this function when the player's state changes.
  //    The function indicates that when playing a video (state=1),
  //    the player should play for six seconds and then stop.
  var done = false;
  function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
    if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
      setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
      done = true;
    }
  }
  function stopVideo() {
    player.stopVideo();
  }
function cueVideo(url) {
    player.cueVideoByUrl(url);
    }
function VideoReady(id) {
    player.loadVideoById(id);
}
```

Python Code:

```
self.driver.execute_script(
                "ytplayer = document.getElementById('player');")
            player_status = self.driver.execute_script(
                "return ytplayer.getPlayerState();")
            print(player_status)
```

Ideally, I want getPlayerState() to return the player's status as -1, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 which will allow me to proceed with the next steps.  If the status code is 0(or finished), then load the next song using selenium.execute_script with the videoId loaded from the Python script.

Edit: Typing console.log(player.getPlayerState()) prints out the actual value for the player.  So getPlayerState() IS A FUNCTION.